# when one value changes how to change another value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have for example such code:

```
scope.people;
scope.agedPeople;
```

If people value changes I need to do this:

```
scope.agedPeople = scope.people * 0.3;
```

And if agedPeople value changes I need to do this:

```
scope.people = scope.agedPeople / 0.3;
```

I wanted to use $watch, but as you can see I have the circular references... I solved it like this:

```
    scope.checkIsPeopleCounted = function() {
      var countedPeople;

      countedPeople = scope.agedPeople * 0.3;

      return countedPeople === scope.people;
    };


    scope.checkIsAgedPeopleCounted = function() {
      var countedAgedPeople;

      countedAgedPeople = scope.people / 0.3;

      return countedAgedPeople === scope.agedPeople;
    };

    scope.$watch('people', function() {
      !scope.checkIsAgedPeopleCounted() && (scope.agedPeople = scope.people / 0.3);
    });

scope.$watch('agedPeople', function() {
  !scope.checkIsPeopleCounted() && (scope.people = scope.agedPeople * 0.3);
});
```

but it looks not very good. maybe there is another solution?

How to make it in angular?

Comment: Please show what you tried? @@

Comment: So, when `people` changes, you want to change `agedPeople`. And then change `people` again, because `agedPeople` changed. And then change `agedPeople`...

Comment: it they are used on input fields then go for `ng-change` a lot better than `$watch`

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit hard without more info. But in theory you can watch values on the scope like so:

```
$scope.$watch('agedPeople', function(newValue, oldValue){});
```

See documentation for Scope.$watch: [Angular Scope.$watch documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

But in your case you have a circular references. You can solve this by adding methods to the scope that returns the result instead.

```
var MULTIPLIER = .3;
$scope.agedPeople = 1;
$scope.people = 1;

$scope.getAgedPeople = function () {
  return $scope.people * MULTIPLIER;
};

$scope.getPeople = function () {
  return $scope.agedPeople * MULTIPLIER;
};
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I have a circular references. I wanted to use $watch, but as you know I have the circular references...

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.$watch("people",function(){
    scope.agedPeople = scoped.people * 0.3;
});
```

And the same thing for agedPeople

Comment: yeah, won't this result in endless mutual change loop?